# Pushing the text down a few pixels from the top in my text area?

Tags: css, textarea, padding

I have a text area in my contact form, nothing too special:

```
<textarea class="txb_message" id="txb_message" name="txb_message" placeholder="What would you like to talk about?"></textarea>
```

But the text doesn't align in the text area as it does in the text boxes above it, and I'm not sure why.

[image: I need to push the content of the text area down]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it vertically aligned to the middle?  Or just adding some padding to the top?

Comment: ^^ `padding`and `top` are the keywords here

Comment: Wow. I need to take a break, how'd I miss that? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top`

```
.txb_message {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add padding to the top of the textarea.

```css
.txb_message {
     padding: 10px 0 0 0;  /* whatever you need */
}
```

Possibly to the sides also since you are using `text-indent` and then remove that for the textarea.  Your final CSS might look like this:

```css
.txb_message {
     padding: 10px;
     text-indent: 0;
}
```

Try filling out your textarea with a bunch of text.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add 15px of padding to the textarea like so :

```
.txb_message {
  height: 68px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```